# How to auto register Vue component files for Laravel Spark

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, laravel-spark

Laravel's app.js file includes some commented out code for adding all vue components under a specified directory:

```
const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i)
files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default))
```

This same code is not included in the latest version of Laravel Spark and does not work when copied over.  How do I auto register any vue component files under a specific directory in Laravel Spark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this code in your app.js file somewhere after importing `Vue` and before instantiating your app's new Vue object:

```
const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i);
files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(files(key).name, files(key)));
```